# How to jump between brackets in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3

Are there shortcuts or plugins for Sublime Text 3 that enable the following functionality?

1. Jump to the inside of the next left bracket or parenthesis
2. Jump to the outside of the next right bracket or parenthesis

Answer (score 84):

## <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>(<kbd>⌃</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> on Mac) for jump between matching brackets.

Also may recommend great plugin [EasyMotion](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/EasyMotion) that allows you to move the cursor to any character without using mouse.

[image]

Comment: cmd-m minimized the window and cmd-shift-m does nothing for me

Comment: @JuJoDi [jump to matching brackets](https://gist.github.com/lucasfais/1207002). I update my answer.

Comment: you...are...my hero...for the day.

Comment: awesome...! just `Ctrl + m`